# Export woocommerce customer emails

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, import, export

I am trying to find a way to export all of my orders from woocommerce to extract the emails of all customers, or just extract the emails.

I tried the following plugin that exports the users, but it seems wordpress only allows 2000 users max?

It says premium will allow customers as well as users.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/

Comment: There is no limit to [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/). You can export all users - email columns only if filtered

Answer (score 0):

I use the following SQL command to extract all the emails from the orders. Users don't need to have an account, it's pulled from the orders.

```
SELECT meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key = '_billing_email'
```